# Accidentally deleted dart package in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I accidentally deleted flutter_material_color_picker-1.1.0+2 package folder that was part of flutter-settings-screens. Now when I try to run the app I get this error:

> ../../MobileDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_settings_screens-0.2.2+1/lib/src/widgets/settings_widgets.dart:3:8: Error: Error when reading '../../MobileDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_material_color_picker-1.1.0+2/lib/flutter_material_color_picker.dart': No such file or directory
> import 'package:flutter_material_color_picker/flutter_material_color_picker.dart';

I tried:

> Deleting pubspec.lock

> flutter clean

Comment: Try to add on `pubspec.yaml` and then `flutter pub get`, if it doesn't solve the case, do `flutter upgrade`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by reinstalling flutter sdk

Answer (score 0):

run `flutter pub add flutter_material_color_picker` so that the package is added again into the project

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

It should solve the issue.